# Is std::mbstate_t state{} guaranteed to zero-initialize the value?

Tags: c++

`mbstate_t` documentation [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstate_t)

> The type `mbstate_t` is a trivial non-array type that can represent any of the conversion states that can occur in an implementation-defined set of supported multibyte character encoding rules. Zero-initialized value of `mbstate_t` represents the initial conversion state...

And [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> ```
> T () ;
> T t = {} ; (2)
> T {} ;
> ```
>
> 2) As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided.

So it seems to me that the combination should guarantee that

```
std::mbstate_t state = std::mbstate_t();
```

(as in the example in [cppreference `std::wcsrtombs` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs)) or

```
std::mbstate_t state{};
```

are guaranteed to zero-initialize the value, because it's a C type and can't be a class with a constructor. Is this correct or am I overlooking something? And if yes, why do other examples (e.g. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/mbsinit/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcsrtombs?view=msvc-160) do something like

```
mbstate_t state;
memset(&state, 0, sizeof(state));
```

Comment: Those are C examples, right?

Comment: The ones at the end? cplusplus.com is not explicit, but MSDN's is certainly C++. But it's very possible that they simply did it because they were porting a C example.

Comment: The standard may say something, the compiler does something other. Do a std::mbstate_t state{}; Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be correct.

[The standard says this about `mbstate_t`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cuchar.syn#lib:mbstate_t):

> The contents and meaning of the header `<cuchar>` are the same as the C
> standard library header `<uchar.h>`, except that it declares the
> additional `mbrtoc8` and `c8rtomb` functions and does not declare types
> `char16_­t` nor `char32_­t`

---

So, going to `<uchar.h>` for C [we have](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  initial  conversion  state  corresponds,  for  a  conversion  in
> either  direction,  to  the beginning   of   a   new   multibyte character   in   the   initial   shift   state. **A zero-valued `mbstate_t` object is (at least) one way to describe an
> initial conversion state**.

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

Saying that a zero-value initialization of `mbstate_t` is one valid way.

As for why the other links do it through `memset` is a mystery to me, however
[further reading](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dinkum_en_c99%2Fuchar.html) gives us:

> Note, however, that other values stored in an object of type `mbstate_t`
> can also represent this state

So it seems that a zero-initialized `mbstate_t` describes a state that can be achieved in multiple ways, zero-initialization being one of them.

---

Perhaps the `memset` variants you linked were accidentally tagged C++ instead of C as it seems that the full example is legal C.